# Extracting information from a txt file and storing into separate array

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that requires a function that is supposed to read students' data from a separate txt file and store the data into a structure [].

For example, if the text file reads:

```
John Doe
50 60 70
9 9 
1 2 3
50 80 90
```

It would store the data into a dynamically allocated structure "studentData" which consists of:

```
struct Student{
string name;
  double * exams;
  double * quizzes;
  double * hw;
  double * labs;
}
```

```
Student* studentsData; // pointer to base address of dynamically allocated array to store data read from file
  ifstream inFile;
  string line;

  inFile.open("grades.txt");
  assert(inFile); // if failed to open file, terminate program with an error message

  //allocate memory for the dynamic array studentsData
   studentsData = new Student[numStudents];
 // for(int i = 0; i < numStudents ; i++)
 while (getline(inFile,line))
      {
          inFile >> line >> studentsData->exams >> studentsData->quizzes >> studentsData->labs >>studentsData->hw;
          studentsData.name = line;


  //store student read from file into the array

  inFile.close();
  return studentsData;
```

Comment: Why does your struct contains double pointers? Why not vectors of doubles?

Comment: Please update your question to include what you have questions about

Comment: You need to read each grade individually or read the entire line and use `stringstream` to get each grade. [Read multiple integers in the same line with cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62865573)

Comment: Before you can do anything useful with `studentsData->exams`, you need to allocate storage for it to point at. How much storage? Well, that can be a bit of a bummer if you don't know ahead of time and that's where Etienne de Martel's suggestion of `vector` can save you a huge amount of time. If you can't use `vector` because of an assignment restriction, you'll want to write your own version as this will almost certainly take less time to write, test, and debug than hacking code directly into `Student` to do the job.